# Cascade delete on duplicate foreign keys? Is that possible?

Tags: sql-server, key, cascade, cascading-deletes

My MSSQL DB design is as follows:

> One table with Images, image_id = PK One table with Videos, video_id
>   = PK One table with Comments, comment_id = PK, and two fields that uniquely match the parent: item_id (equals either image_id or
>   video_id) and item_type which tells me who is the parent (either an
>   image or a video).

How can I add a Cascading Delete, so that when I delete an image, it automatically deletes the comments matching `Images.image_id = Comments.item_id AND Comments.item_type = 'image'`? As you see, for this to work I have to specify both the item type and `item_id` since another comment can exist on the same `item_id` but with different `item_type` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`TRIGGER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx), This allows you to include the necessary `c.item_type = 'image'` filter:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TrgImagesDelete] ON [dbo].[Images] FOR DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    DELETE c
    FROM
        Comments c
        JOIN Deleted d
            ON c.item_id = d.image_id
            AND c.item_type = 'image'
END
GO
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i was looking for a non-trigger solution. If it can't be done otherwise, i think i better do it via code and send 2 delete statements wrapped inside a tranzaction statement. Is that ok in your opinion?

Comment: @osmiumbin Yes, that sounds like a good solution to me as well.

Comment: @osmiumbin I understand wanting to avoid triggers, since they can be difficult to troubleshoot if they're used liberally, but just note that the application approach doesn't give you a guarantee in the database that the rule is being followed... there may come a point in the future where a different portion of the application implements the delete differently, and doesn't cleanup the comment as it should... just something to keep in mind.

Comment: Thanks, i'll remember that. What nonclustered indexes do you advice i should create on Comments table since all the searches are done by item_id, user_id, and item_type?

Comment: Do you ever search by just `user_id`?  If you do, I would start with an index on `item_id` and another on `user_id`.  If you never search by just `user_id`, then I would start with just one index on `item_id` and go from there...